# Keyboard layout changes in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, 13.10

I use a Norwegian keyboard layout in Ubuntu. I did a clean install on my Asus K52F. Every time I turn on the laptop, the layout is set to English (or some other language, I can't really tell). The same thing happens whenever the laptop goes into screensaver mode and I try to log in with my password when prompted. I've searched the forums and Askubuntu, but I haven't found a solution to this problem. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 ? There are quite a number of related bug in the description, the one you are looking for could be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1244548

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198. I get similar with everything resetting to English (US) on boot.

One workaround appears to be to go into a different vterm and then back again (alt-ctrl-f1 then alt-ctrl-f7). This will need to be done each time the layout resets though.